# simulation cache playback

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, smoke-simulation, fluid-simulation, cloth-simulation

my question is how to make blender refreshes viewport playback cache every time when the timeline starts from the beginning, say i have 250 frame, everytime it plays all the 250 frames and jump back to the first frame, i want it to recalculate the simulation from the scratch, not using the cache from the previous playback. that way i can always see the realtime effect of my adjustment, so i dont have to go into edit mode and out to refresh it. i remembered when i used 2.8 cache will always refresh when a new playback starts. im using 2.82 right now. when i do simulations, sometine cache refreshes sometimes dont. so how to make it refresh all the time?